# Protractor needs to wait for Angular progress spinner

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, spinner, ui-automation

I am using cucumber framework and one of the pages that i am testing that a angular progress-spinner. I want my test to wait for the spinner to disappear before doing anything.

```
  this.Then('I should see Page Displayed', function () {
          return browser.getTitle().then(function (text) {
        // console.log('Title of Displayed Page is -' + text);
        expect(text).to.equal('Schedule Page');
      })
  });
```

I tried adding the below but it did not help

```
       var el = element(by.css('mat-spinner'));
      browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsNotVisible(el));
```

Comment: I use something like `browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(your spinner selector));`

Comment: can you pls elaborate. It still does not work. Thanks